# Why MySQL slave stops syncing with error 1449?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-replication

I have implemented a replica from a MySQL database. The issue is, after 2 days, the slave doesn't get sync anymore and it throws:

> Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at source log mysql-bin.000004, end_log_pos 4321483. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.

Also, the `Last_SQL_Errno` is `1449`. Any idea what's the issue and how can I make it working/syncing with master again?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is this related to the configuration you have made on your question [Algorithm of MySQL Master-Slave Replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329977/algorithm-of-mysql-master-slave-replication) ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Not really

Comment: @MartinAJ have you verified the *See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any* ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error 1449 means, that a user which exists on source, doesn't exist on replica, and therefore replica cannot execute the statement. Most likely this is a a CREATE (view/trigger/procedure) with a definer which doesn't exist on the replica.

You can check the command and user by using the `mysqlbinlog` tool on the replica machine:

`mysqlbinlog --read-from-remote-server --host=source_server -uusername mysql-bin.000004 --j 4321483`